# Vapour-tight lustre block connection

Tags: connector

I have to connect a two-wire cable in a continuously extremely humid & warm environment. While there are no safety issues due to low voltages the connection corrodes within a few weeks: the corrosion even creeps a way into the wires.

I am looking for a way to make the connection water- and vapour-tight without making it too bulky or too permanent.

I ruled out classical boxes for electrical installations with seals because they are too bulky (about 10 cm minimum) and self-fusing tape because it is practically impossible to open.

Any suggestions on what to use? I am ok to relax the vapour-tight requirement if good corrosion resistance can be achieved without it.

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time finding a setscrew termination for sealed connectors.  Can you relax the requirement of having it use setscrews and deal with crimped terminals?  You'll have much more available to you that way, and by much more, I mean that I've never sealed an environmentally-rated sealed connector that had setscrew terminals... ever.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the vast supplies of industrial-class waterproof connectors ([example](http://www.weipuconnector.com/productcatalognew.htm)). You will find a wide variety of those on ebay and alibaba for a reasonable price.
Most of them have a similar construction: you plug it in and screw the cap tight: water-tight, thanks to the O-ring. 
[image]